# SAN and Hyper V

Tags: hyper-v, storage, storage-area-network

I have just configured SCV2020 Dell Storage to be used with a Cluster of Hyper V servers. Everything is working fine. I have a more of a design question.

Should I create one large volume on the dell storage let's say 2TB and then map it on both servers and create all VMs not this volume?

OR

Should I create a separate volume for each VM?

In any case I still have to add the disk to server and give it a drive letter etc. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll usually create a single Volume/LUN/Virtual Disk on your storage array and create a single Cluster Shared Volume from that on your Hyper-V hosts. You'll then provision your VM's virtual hard drives out of that single CSV rather than provisioning individual Volumes/LUNs/Virtual Disks on your storage array for individual VM's.

As for how to do it, how are you connecting the Hyper-V hosts to the storage? FC, iSCSI, et.?

Comment: Thanks. I was going down that path but then I realised if I ever have to move one VM to the second node let's say because the first server has a lot of load, then with one Volume it won't be possible correct? As the failover would want the whole volume be assigned to second server?

Comment: A Cluster Shared Volume (CSV) is a clustered volume that is shared and accessed by both Hyper-V hosts at the same time. The VM's  virtual hard drive(s) live on the CSV. If a VM migrates from one host to the other (either manually initiated by you or as a result of a host failure) the VM state (memory contents) moves from one host to the other but the VM's virtual hard drive(s) stay on the CSV. The virtual hard drives never move from the CSV during a VM migration.

Comment: https://www.petri.com/create-windows-server-2012-r2-cluster-shared-volume

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj612868(v=ws.11).aspx

Comment: To clarify my previous comment, if a clustered Hyper-V host fails, the VM's that were hosted on that Hyper-V host are (re)started on the other Hyper-V host. Only in the event of a migration (not a failover) would the VM state be migrated to the other host. In the case of a host failure the VM state can't be migrated because the VM crashes when the host crashes.

Comment: Thanks mate. This resolved the problem for me. I did come across this in another article but for some reason didn't make much sense but the links you have shared are good.

Comment: Glad to help...

Answer (score 5):

It's up to you, however you will have one cluster out of these CSVs.

For example, there is quite large amount of VMs in our environment, and we just sorted them on different volumes by departments. That's easier to manage.

> if I ever have to move one VM to the second node let's say because the
>   first server has a lot of load, then with one Volume it won't be
>   possible correct?

After placing VMs on the CSV, you can load balance each VM by setting the priority of Virtual Machines in VM properties.

Comment: You can use multiple CSV's per cluster. For instance if you have multiple storage arrays or storage tiers/types (HDD versus SSD).

Comment: @joeqwerty yeah, thx, I meant that. Edited